# Does this mean I have "guessed" a Windows Server password?

Tags: windows, windows-server

Windows Server 2003 ... Long story short I am trying to determine an account password without resetting it. Working remotely and this is a production server so ophcrack or the like is not viable.

I tried to logon with a password I know was incorrect. Got the expected "could not log on; check your credentials" message.

Then I tried the password that I *think* is correct, and I got the "policy does not allow this account to log on remotely" message.

So does this mean it's the right password?  (I need to know **FOR SURE**.)

And, this is not for any nefarious purpose, and I am a legitimate and authorized admin of the machine in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you guessed it right.

The server is telling you that the user account used by you is not allowed to log in via remote desktop. That user has to be in the local group "Remote Desktop Users". 
The check for login permissions is only done when the user was correctly authenticated.